# Netsh command on Windows XP

Tags: networking, windows-xp, gateway, netsh, vsphere

When trying to change default gateway on windows xp on vm machine using the following command:
`set address name="Local Area Connection" source=dhcp addr=192.168.25.22 mask=255.255.255.0 gateway=192.168.31.3`
Command didn't change anything.
Any idea why?
( I tried to launch it when I already had a default gateway configured and also after I deleted the gateway)

In addition , I tried to add at the beginning of command: 
`netsh interface ipv4` or even `netsh int ipv4`
But it said "The following command was not found"

Comment: Add just `netsh interface ip` before `set...`

Comment: @DavidPostill: It's not working

Comment: According to [Netsh commands for Interface IP](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/netsh_int_ip.mspx?mfr=true) `netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" source=dhcp addr=192.168.25.22 mask=255.255.255.0 gateway=192.168.31.3` should work from a command line. What exact error message are you getting when you run this?

Comment: What is the output from `netsh interface ip show interface "Local Area Connection"`?

Comment: @DavidPostill: "The syntax supplied for this command is not valid"

Comment: Hmm. `netsh interface ip show interface "Local Area Connection"` runs fine here (Windows 7). Are you running in a Virtual Machine?

Comment: @DavidPostill: Yes indeed, windows xp - virtual machine

Comment: Ok. Then it's a problem with your VM. I can't help with that. I suggest you [edit] the question to make it clear you are running XP in a VM.